# Does 0 means true in bash ? and !0 means false?

Tags: bash, return-value, logical-operators, conventions

I'm asking a straight forward question, does 0 means true in shell? and !0 means false?

```
[server@user]$ [[ 1 == 1 ]] && echo $?
0

[server@user]$ [[ 1 == 0 ]] || echo $?
1
```

And tried to make a function to return 0:

```
[server@user]$ function false(){ return 0;}
[server@user]$ false && echo How this can be true?
How this can be true?
```

I know that the convention sais that `0` means `successful`, but does it means `true` in logical operators too?

Comment: bash has no idea of true and false. The closest to this concept is the evaluation of the exit code. If you write `if COMMAND; then x; else; y; fi`, the _then_ branch is taken if _COMMAND_ terminates with exit code 0, and the _else_ branch if the exit code is something different. Similarily, `&&` and `||` are defined in terms of exit code only.

Comment: Thats a very good point, then we can say, that the behaviour of (exit code 0) is the same as behaviour of (true) boolean value in logical statements, conditions ...

Comment: Restricting to logical statements, yes. But it's not a full boolean arithmetic, more akin to languages like Perl, where, due to the lack of real boolean values, certain other values behave like true and others behave like false. Also you can not really store a "boolean" into a variable. Even if you do a `flag=$?`, what is really stored in _flag_ is a string, with all properties you expect from a string. Actually, the string is the only "data type" available to bash.

Comment: Nice, I think you may form this in an answer, it is so informative

Comment: Aside from the fact, that your question does not accept answers anymore, my comment targets more a general concept of what's in a boolean data type.